# MVC Project Design, pros and cons of re-using Partial Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a question for the pros and cons on how reusable partial views should be used in a project.

In the first example, I have a layout that is used between all the views. In the layout, I have a partial view that gets called using `Html.RenderAction("Index", "Header")`. This header changes based on if the user is logged in or not and it renders on every view.

In the second example, I have a static layout that is used between all the views. However, in this layout there are no partial views being called. The Header partial view is being called on each view and basically does the same thing as the first example (changes based on if a user is logged in or not, etc.)

Which approach is better, is one way or another the correct way? Pros and cons of each?

Comment: *However, in this layout there is no partial views being called. The Header partial view is being called on each view...*  Doesn't this contradict itself?

Comment: The header partial view is being called on the actual Views themselves and not from within the layout view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main ideas behind [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) is to not reuse code. So with this in mind, you should have your `Header` code in your `_Layout` file. This way it is not being retyped in every `View`, and if you needed to remove it or add route values, etc you do not have to update every `View` that has it.

An example of this is the `_LogOnPartial` that is in a default project. In the `_Layout` it is called by `@Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")`, and the `_LogOnPartial` view contains a logic statement that either displays `LogOn or Register` or `Welcome back...`.